# Ether Address returned is different (second half) from the one stored in contract's array

Tags: solidity, addresses

I have a simple setter and getter for address[] type array in a contract.

I deployed the contracts on testrpc using truffle.

Then in truffle console:

> truffle(development)>
>
> lot.addNewUserToLottery(24,0xf392261711006934215e47025275f98b3c156568, {value:50000})

Returns:

```
{ tx: '0x5ed462b5f80578609223827cc9dea8a51ef2e6920f197734ce6c64b0cbebf372',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0x5ed462b5f80578609223827cc9dea8a51ef2e6920f197734ce6c64b0cbebf372',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x4015c50e9a5721466c007cade050671cb8fa3b768295a1793e0683e8613e4aa9',
     blockNumber: 459,
     gasUsed: 74162,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 74162,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [ [Object] ],
     status: '0x01',
     logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' },
  logs: [] }
```

But when i call the getter:

> truffle(development)> lot.getUserAddress(24,0);

I get the address :

```
'0xf3922617110067aaf6e0168134a72bed00000000'
```

Similarly for other addresses stored:

> 0x83bf9513ceaa869a6b1e847f4f0caa47dc1441b4
>
> returns
>
> 0x83bf9513ceaa85b568c5a6858ba4640700000000

Why is the address' second half being changed by solidity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it was a very lame mistake.

I was calling function from truffle console like:

> lot.addNewUserToLottery(24,0xf392261711006934215e47025275f98b3c156568,
>   {value:50000})

When one should be using single quotes around address :

> lot.addNewUserToLottery(24,'0xf392261711006934215e47025275f98b3c156568',
>   {value:50000})

EVM was accepting the parameter but was changing the address.

Hope someone doesn't make it and if does then find this helpful.